How to Launch Notepad++ from Angular 18 Project on Button Click?
I'm working on an Angular 18 project and I need to implement a functionality where clicking a button opens Notepad++ software. I tried using the Electron package but didn't achieve the desired result. Can anyone provide guidance or a solution on how to successfully integrate this feature into my Angular project? Specifically, I want clicking a button in my Angular application to launch Notepad++ on the user's system. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Generally speaking, you should be able to use exec from Node's child_process module.  Read the documentation for detailed information.
I don't program Electron (or server JavaScript for that matter), but seems to be pretty straightforward:
exec("path/to/executable");

Make this call whenever it is convenient, like the click of a button.
